# Add two modal-content inside bootstrap modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to add two `modal-content` divs inside a single `modal`.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="user_manage_modal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
         <!-- Assign Users -->
             <div class="modal-content">...</div>
         <hr>
         <!-- UnAssign Users -->
             <div class="modal-content">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks all great but I wanted to add a horizontal line between two `modal-content` divs.

And the output looks like this:
[image: modal-img]

I have added no extra css for this.

Expected just a simple horizontal line in between:

[image]
Is it because multiple `modal-contents` are not allowed inside a `bootstrap modal`?

Comment: Do you want both modals to be together (without the space in between) and with a border between them?

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres updated the post.

Comment: Which Bootstrap version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You will have todo all your styling (as you did not give the rest of the code) inside the modal-content

```
<div class="modal fade" id="user_manage_modal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Assign Users -->
           <hr>
          <!-- UnAssign Users -->
      </div>
  </div>
```

Since you only gave a fragment be aware of the following structure = sequence in bootstrap modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal-demo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" >
    <div class="modal-content"> 
      <div class="modal-header"> optional
      <div class="modal-body"> 
      <div class="modal-footer"> optional
```

As this classes (and the js code attached) have to be in the sequence (and are expected by the js-code to be single applied per modal) you have two choices for "special purposes"

- Do all formating, button attaching in the

  ```
  <div class="modal-body">
  ```
- or copy the needed css into a new class like

  ```
  <div class="my-modal-content">
  ```

  removing all unwanted effects and loosing the js-function based on that (if of course there are some attached or use the class description)